# How to check authentication in SvelteKit?

Tags: authentication, web, storage, svelte, sveltekit

I want to check if the user is logged in when they visit the route /login and, if so, redirect them to /. The same happens vice versa if they are not logged in as well.

I want to put something like:

```js
export async function load() {
    const res = await fetch("[endpoint]", {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${localStorage.jwt}`
        },
        credentials: "include"
    });
    const json = await res.json();
    return {
        logged_in: json.logged_in
    };
}
```

in my +page.js (or +page.server.js?) but this doesn't work as it says localStorage is undefined.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: you shouldn't use localStorage for this but rather cookies, you can read those in the handle, and pass them with `event.locale` to the different endpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LocaleStorage in Sveltekit is a bit tricky](https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/p438og/how_to_access_localstorage_via_store_in_sveltekit/), but there are ways around it, like checking to see if your code is being executed on the client's browser, like so:

```
import { browser } from '$app/env'

export async function load(){
    if (browser) {
        // Do stuff here
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

A solution that's worked for me is chucking this code into the `<script context="module">` of a base `__layout.svelte` that every layout inherits from.

For instance, you could have a `__layout.svelte` that consists of nothing more than this code. Building off of what Stephane pointed out, if you don't want to use cookies (e.g. a jwt token with a very limited lifespan) you could use session storage;

```
<script context="module">
export async function load({ fetch, session }) {
    const res = await fetch("[endpoint]", {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${session.jwt}`
        },
        credentials: "include"
    });
    const json = await res.json();
    return {
        logged_in: json.logged_in
    };
}
</script>

<slot />
```

(You can read more about `load()` [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load))

And then have other layouts that inherit this layout by having a layout like `__layout-auth@default.svelte`. You can read more about named layouts [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing).